# on scroll function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am developing a plugin with jquery which shrinks menu on scroll at a specific `scrollTop`. I am using `scrollTop` function to get the top value; it shows current position properly on console. But there is a problem on next step. My code is:

```
;(function($) {

    'use strict'

    $.fn.orvilnav = function( options ){
        var defaults = {
            menuShrinkable : true,
            menuChanageOn : 40
        },

        options = $.extend(defaults, options);


        var menuShrinks = defaults.menuShrinkable,
            menuChangeOn = defaults.menuChangeOn,

            menu        = $(this),
            scrolled    = false,
            yPosition   = $(window).scrollTop();


            $(window).on('scroll', function(){
                if(menuShrinks){
                    if(yPosition > menuChangeOn){
                        console.log('ok');
                    }
                }
            })
    }

})(jQuery);
```

and my code implementation is

```
$('nav.orvilnav').orvilnav();
```

here `menuChangeOn` is an option at which scrollTop menu will change.
But it does not console 'ok' :(

Comment: Add more `console.log`s. Is the event handler being called? Is the `if(menuShrinks)` working? Or is it the inner `if`?

Comment: if i use `if($(window).scrollTop() > 50){
                 console.log('ok');
             }` it works

Answer (score 0):

You have to fix typo in defaults:

```
var defaults = {
    menuShrinkable : true,
    menuChangeOn : 40 // not menuChanageOn
},
```

Then try use:

```
if($(window).scrollTop() > menuChangeOn){
    console.log('ok');
}
```

`yPosition = $(window).scrollTop();` is never changed in the `on scroll` event.

Btw, I think your `menuShrinks = defaults.menuShrinkable` should be `menuShrinks = options.menuShrinkable`.

See a demo fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jathvd9c/2/

Comment: not works , but if use 40 instead of `menuChangeOn` then works

Comment: @muhaimin in your defaults, you have a typo ` menuChanageOn`

Comment: if i console.log `menuChangeOn` it comes undefined